# Where do I provide the service option for SRV in AWS Route3

Tags: amazon-aws, route53, srv-records

I have two servers on different ports of the same IP address, one on IP:80, and the other on IP:1034. I have a domain example.com, and I want to link IP:80 to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and also want to like IP:1034 to dupe.example.com. My domains are registered with Route53, and I am using an A record for example.com, linking it to IP, and when I go to example.com I see my server working. I tried using an SRV record on AWS, and he is my configuration: [image: Configuration]

At the bottom, it says the format is: [priority] [weight] [port] [server host name], which is what I entered.
The server does not seem to load on dupe.domain.com. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use SRV with HTTP and HTTPS.   The protocols do not support SRV.  SRV was invented after the web and the spec for SRV specifically says that protocols must explicitly state that they want to use it.  Old protocols (such as HTTP) won't be able to use it.

It doesn't matter how you create SRV records at Amazon because you won't be able to use them for your website.

The usual way to solve your problem is to create two virtual hosts on the server running on port 80.  For the subdomain, the virtual host can run a reverse proxy to get the content from the other port.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at that and see if there is anything else I am struggling with.